# Laravel правильно обрабатывать полученные данные и записывать в поле

Tags: laravel, события, сервисы

Есть сущность `Article`, в которой есть поле `first_leter`. В данное поле, при создании или обновлении сущности нужно записывать первую русскую букву другого поля (title). Если первый символ латинский, записывать "A-Z", если цифра то "0-9".
Я хочу сделать некую функцию, которая будет принимать строку и возвращать уже результат.

Каким образом это правильно реализовать во фреймворке Laravel. С помощью обработчиков событий, или с помощью сервиса, или создавать хелпер? Подскажите как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простейший вариант...

```
class Article extends Model{
  public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    self::created(function($client){ $client->write();});
    self::updated(function($client){ $client->write();});
  }
  private function write(){
    $this->first_leter = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/', $this->title[0])) ? 'A-Z' : preg_match('/^\d$/', $this->title[0])) ? '0-9' : null;
    $this->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Возникает ошибка - Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting! после добавления этих 2 методов в модель.
http://joxi.ru/vAWJB1EH11ke12